# Use of Unresolved Identifier Error Code

Tags: swift

I was wondering why I keep getting the error message, Use of Unresolved Identifier 'ChangeInPercent'. I am not really sure why I keep getting this error message could somebody help, I would really appreciate it.

Here is the code.

```
import UIKit

class StocksTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

//1
private var stocks: [(String,Double)] = [("AAPL",+1.5),("FB",+2.33),("GOOG",-4.3)]
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //2
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "stocksUpdated:", name: kNotificationStocksUpdated, object: nil)
    self.updateStocks()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

//UITableViewDataSource
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return stocks.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "cellId")
    cell.textLabel!.text = stocks[indexPath.row].0 //position 0 of the tuple: The Symbol "AAPL"
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "\(stocks[indexPath.row].1)" + "%" //position 1 of the tuple: The value "1.5" into String
    return cell
}

//UITableViewDelegate
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}

//Customize the cell
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    switch stocks[indexPath.row].1 {
    case let x where x < 0.0:
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 59.0/255.0, blue: 48.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    case let x where x > 0.0:
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 76.0/255.0, green: 217.0/255.0, blue: 100.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    case _:
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 44.0/255.0, green: 186.0/255.0, blue: 231.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    cell.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.detailTextLabel!.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.textLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold", size: 48)
    cell.detailTextLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold", size: 48)
    cell.textLabel!.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25)
    cell.textLabel!.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
    cell.detailTextLabel!.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25)
    cell.detailTextLabel!.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
}

//Customize the height of the cell
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 120
}

//Stock updates
//3
func updateStocks() {
    let stockManager:StockManagerSingleton = StockManagerSingleton.sharedInstance
    stockManager.updateListOfSymbols(stocks)

    //Repeat this method after 15 secs. (For simplicity of the tutorial we are not cancelling it never)
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(15 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(),
        {
            self.updateStocks()
        }
    )
}

//4
func stocksUpdated(notification: NSNotification) {
    let values = (notification.userInfo as! Dictionary<String,NSArray>)
    let stocksReceived:NSArray = values[kNotificationStocksUpdated]!
    stocks.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    for quote in stocksReceived {
        let quoteDict:NSDictionary = quote as! NSDictionary
        var changeInPercentString = quoteDict["ChangeInPercent"] as! String
        let changeInPercentStringClean: NSString = (changeInPercentString as NSString).substringToIndex(ChangeInPercent(changeInPercentString)-1)
        stocks.append(quoteDict["symbol"] as! String,changeInPercentStringClean.doubleValue)
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
    NSLog("Symbols Values updated :)")
}
}
```

The line of code with the error is,

```
var changeInPercentString = quoteDict["ChangeInPercent"] as! String
```

Comment: Are you sure its this line? I think its the next line causing error

Comment: Where did you define `ChangeInPercent` (the function)?

Comment: Sorry, yes the next line is causing it. @jithin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var changeInPercentString = quoteDict["ChangeInPercent"] as! String
let changeInPercentStringClean: NSString = (changeInPercentString as NSString).substringToIndex((changeInPercentString as NSString).length-1)
```

Comment: when I input your code it says "Binary operator '-' could not be applied. @Pradeep K

Comment: Updated the code. I am presuming that you are trying to skip the last char of the `changeInPercentString`. For e.g. If `changeInPercentString` is 44% then you are trying to get 44 in `changeInPercentStringClean`, Right?

Comment: When I build and run it says Sigabrt. 2016-02-29 22:43:10.791 StockCountApp[6702:624341] Unknown class _TtC13StockCountApp24StockTableViewController in Interface Builder file.
2016-02-29 22:43:10.842 StockCountApp[6702:624341] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7f95d3e46340> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tableView.' @Pradeep K

Comment: Make sure that the file is included in your project and also the view controller's custom class is set? Also did you drag a table view controller and change it custom class or did you drag a UIViewController? Since you have derived from UIViewController you have to drag the same class and then add a table view and set the connection

Comment: I made a ViewController then dragged a tableView onto that then made a connection to the tableView. What do you mean by drag the same class? @Pradeep K

Comment: I meant you have to drag a UIViewController itself to the storyboard. Anyways check the custom class setting and see if it matches your class name. What's the custom class that is set in the Custom Class field in storyboard?

Comment: The custom class is StockTableViewController @Pradeep K

Comment: What is NSUnknownKeyException @Pradeep K